# Multiple Methods Named boolValue

Tags: objective-c

Im suddenly getting a error through out one of my classes.
The error is

```
Multiple methods named 'boolValue' found with mismatched result, type or attributes.
```

Here is the code getting the error,

```
[cell2.LBL_Detail  setHidden:[[mArr_isAnswered objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]boolValue]];
```

and

```
    BOOL detailed = [[mArr_isAnswered objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] boolValue];
```

Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: Post the `@interface` for the class with this `boolValue` method.

Comment: Have you created class with method named boolValue? This method already exist in apple framework so you shouldn't use this name for custom method. What object do you store in mArr_isAnswered array?

Comment: 1. I have not created a class with boolValue. 2. I am storing the primitive BOOL type data in the array. ... I have already checked for uses of BoolValue in my method names using the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like Xcode can see multiple `boolValue` selectors in your project (or libraries used by your project) and they return different data types (`BOOL` would be the expected data type, it would reckon).

Xcode also doesn't know what class is contained in the `NSArray` so you can quieten it down by either:

1. Casting the return type of the array access to the correct class:

   ```
   BOOL detailed = [(SomeClass *)[mArr_isAnswered objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] boolValue];
   ```
2. Fix all `boolValue` methods to return the same type (`BOOL`).

Comment: I imported a custom object with a property called boolValue. Thanks.